# How can I enable GHC extensions in a literate Haskell script?

Tags: haskell, ghci

I'm working on a literate Haskell script that defines a Grammar datatype that is to be loaded into GHCI (v. 7.8.3) on my Mac.  I am trying to turn on language extensions called KindSignatures and GADTs in my script (I am completely unfamiliar with these) but I've been advised to include the line

```
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures, GADTs #-}
```

at the top of my script.  But I get an error message:

```
Grammars.lhs:5:3:
    Illegal kind signature ‘Grammar’
      (Use KindSignatures to allow kind signatures)
    In the data declaration for ‘Grammar’
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?  Also is there any kind of documentation on KindSignatures or GADTs?  I've been unable to find much.

Comment: Although this is essentially unrelated to your problem, [GADTs](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/data-type-extensions.html#gadt) have nearly become ubiquitous so they are quite well documented.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since it is a literate script, you need to escape the pragma like other literate code:

```
> {-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures, GADTs #-}
```

or

```
\begin{code}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures, GADTs #-}
\end{code}
```

dependent on which literate style you are using.

Comment: Oh dear, as simple as that!  Thanks a lot, that's fixed it.